# Cannot start new project with Android Studio

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I just started using Linux Ubuntu, and downloaded and maybe set up Android Studio.

When I launch it, it does successfully, though it took hours to come here. But it gives me now :

`Your Android SDK is missing, out of date, or is missing templates. Please ensure you are using SDK version 22 or later. You can configure your SDK via Configure | Project Defaults | Project Structure | SDKs`

I tried to do so and at SDKs I added Android SDK. But when I clicked "ok", the prompt was dismissed but nothing happened, that is, not added.
I tried "Android SDK" two items below SDKs, because Android SDK was empty. But this time, Apply button and OK button doesn't respond. When I look at command line at the moment this error was being displayed.

```
[ 550663]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio (Preview) 0.4.6  Build #AI-133.1028713 
[ 550663]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_05 
[ 550663]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
[ 550664]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: Oracle Corporation
[ 550670]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux
```

It looks like there isn't relavant answer to this. All the questions tend to end with  concluding "That's easy. Go Config, project default, project structure, and add Android SDK and Voila! You're good to go." Unfortunately no voila to me, so I here post this.

If anyone has an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Android Studio 5.7 and jdk 7 in Ubuntu 14.04 without problems.

I'm not expert but i thought you was using an old android studio version and a new jdk version.

I searched:

You are using android studio 0.4.6 based on IntelliJ 13.0 
http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio050released

And IntelliJ adds support for JDK 8 in 13.1 version
http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/intellij-idea-13-1-released/

So try to upgrade Android Studio to 5.0 (based on 13.1) or better downgrade JDK version to 7 if you dont need it, perhaps not completely supported.

Comment: I thought I just downloaded the newest version but it may have been not. It solved when I re-downloaded the same(as I believe so) as I was using.

Answer (score 6):

I have fix this ishue on Ubuntu 14.04, Android Studio 0.8 ::

```
sudo chmod 775 -R {your path}/android-studio/
```

In my case Studio were placed in /usr/local/android-studio ::

```
/usr/local/android-studio/android-studio/
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and this worked for me. Thank you @Biosonic

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue but on a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04, a fresh download of Android Studio 0.5.7, Oracle Java 8, Gradle 1.12 and the Android ADT Bundle 20140321. Every time I tried to bring up the Project Defaults to set the Android SDK location an exception appeared on the console with the same message you posted.

Before starting I set the various tool HOME environment variables to where those tools were installed, (which could be optional if you're installing all of these through the Ubuntu package manager..)

```
export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/DEV/gradle
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/DEV/jdk
export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/DEV/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

Then,

1. From the quick start dialog (presented when you first open Android Studio if you don't have a project already created) disable the Android Plugins found under Configure -> Plugins. Also disable any plugins Android Studio recommends when you disable the Android ones.
2. Restart Android Studio when prompted.
3. Add the Java JDK via Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings: SDKs
4. Apply changes, head back into Configure -> Plugins and re-enable the Android Plugins.
5. Restart Android Studio when prompted.
6. Set the Android SDK Location and JDK Location under Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure. When I did it, it was pre-filled so I just hit Apply.
7. Restart Android Studio
8. The SDK Manager is now a visible button under Configure and you can now create a new Android Project.

Upon creating a new Android Project, Android Studio then went off and download the various dependencies and Gradle 1.10. Annoying that it downloaded Gradle again, but at least Android Studio started to work after that.